# java tieredcompilation - spike in sample program

Tags: java, jit

I'm trying to understand a strange behavior of JIT tiered compilation (-XX:+TieredCompilation).

My sample program looks like this:

```
public class SimpleProgram {
  static final int CHUNK_SIZE = 1_000;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    for ( int i = 0; i < 500; ++i ) {
      long startTime = System.nanoTime();

      for ( int j = 0; j < CHUNK_SIZE; ++j ) {
        new Object();
      }

      long endTime = System.nanoTime();
      System.out.printf("%d\t%d%n", i, endTime - startTime);
    }
  }
}
```

I know that this benchmark is invalid and `new Object();` with the whole loop will be removed by JIT. That is the point of this sample program.

When I execute the program I'm getting something like this for the results

- iterations 0-73 - 35000 ns
- iterations 74-252 - 15000 ns
- iterations 253+ 50 ns

This shows exactly what I want and I understand the results.

What I do not understand is that every time I execute this program around iteration 150 the logged time is 50 ns.

The exact iteration varies, but this spike is always there. This should not be a second tier compilation as it will happen much latter. So what is causing this single loop to be so fast?

I was executing this code on multiple machines witch different versions of java/OS/processors and the unexpected spike was always there.

Comment: By "spike" do you mean a sudden *drop* in runtime? That's the opposite of a spike.

Comment: Its a _drop_ in runtime but _spike_ in performance. But still thanks for looking at it form this perspective.

Comment: @RobertOzga ... I know this is 2+ years old post. But did you figure out what was happening under the hood? I tried this code and I did not see the spike (JRE 1.8). Around 130-150 iteration, server compiler is getting involved. When I moved '("%d\t%d%n", i, endTime - startTime);' to an ArrayList<String>, server compiler triggered around 200th iteration. So CPU time might be contributing to this.